# LDAPS with AD Server 2008R2 certreq -accept fails

Tags: active-directory, ssl-certificate

I'm having the issue listed here:
[Active Directory SSL Certificate Private Key Not Attached](https://serverfault.com/questions/319469/active-directory-ssl-certificate-private-key-not-attached)

however they don't explain what to do to fix the private key not attached if the certreq -accept fails.

I'm using an external CA, and I can import the certs just fine via the GUI.

certreq -accept certname.cer returns the following error:

```
certificate request processor 
cannot find object or property 0x80092004 (-2146885628)
```

Googling doesn't seem to find anything related to my problem, most links are about IE9 or SQL server which don't seem related to AD LDAPS to me.

Anyone know what the problem is? And how to fix it?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using for certreq -accept, and what is the error?

Comment: certreq -accept dc4_domain_edu.cer

Comment: The error is exactly listed above, I get a pop-up dialog saying that with a red X error circle.

Comment: View the properties of the certificate file on the DC where you generated original request, does it say that "you have private key for this cert"? //Edit: also check if the subject name matches your DC name

Comment: It doesn't say that if I select it and say "open", or at least I don't know where to look. The Subject is dc4.domain.edu .... the netbios name is DC4. I don't know if it's a capitalization issue, I entered in my request form for the CA the cn capitalized, and dns name has the correct dns name with all lower case.

Comment: it should look like http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-07-77-60-72/140208F.png. 
server's FQDN must match certificate "issue to"(subject) field. If you don't have private key, it won't work (and you probably generated your CSR on a different machine, or on the same token, you are using a cert for a different machine.

Comment: Is the certificate still in the Certificate Enrollment Requests store on the computer where you created the request/are accepting the certificate?

Comment: It is the same computer. I'm guessing it's the DC4 vs dc4 in issued to... Let me try changing to lower case in my certreq.inf and trying again.

Comment: It looks like it was indeed the upper case vs lower case, somewhere between 3 years ago and yesterday the subject alternate name stopped working with either our CA or windows...

Comment: I have to agree with strongline.  It seems likely to me that the cert request was generated on another machine from where it was accepted, or the certificate was no longer present in the Certificate Enrollment Requests store on the computer where you created.  Accepting a certificate that does not exist in the Certificate Enrollment Requests store generates that exact error message.  The CN of the certificate subject does not have to match the computer name or case.  You should be able to create a certificate for any name you want.